# Python Bokeh pie chart colors, how to change

Tags: python, charts, colors, bokeh, pie-chart

I have a palette:

```
chart_colors = ['#44e5e2', '#e29e44', '#e244db',
                '#d8e244', '#eeeeee', '#56e244', '#007bff', 'black']
```

And a pie chart which is generated by Bokeh.

```
x = Counter({
    'Submitted': 179,
    'Approved': 90,
    'Denied': 80
})

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(x), orient='index').reset_index().rename(
    index=str, columns={0: 'value', 'index': 'claimNumber'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/sum(x.values()) * 2*pi
data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]

p = figure(plot_height=200,
           tooltips="@claimNumber: @value",
           name='claimChart')

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.28,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        line_color="white", fill_color='color', legend='claimNumber', source=data)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Now fill_color='color' and color is defined as 'data['color'] = Category20c[len(x)]'.

In older versions it's possible to provide 'color' (p.wedge(..., color=...), but I use Bokeh 0.13.0, so I have only fill_color='color' for each color.

How I can change data['color'] to the color from my 'chart_colors' array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I use Bokeh 0.13.0, so I have only fill_color='color' for each color.

This is not true. The `color` argument is available to to any glyph method (including `wedge`) is just a convenience to set both `fill_color` and `line_color` at the same time.  Your question is somewhat confusing since the size of your palette does not match the size of your data, but here is a complete example that simply uses the palette, truncated:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import cumsum

chart_colors = ['#44e5e2', '#e29e44', '#e244db',
                '#d8e244', '#eeeeee', '#56e244', '#007bff', 'black']

x = Counter({
    'Submitted': 179,
    'Approved': 90,
    'Denied': 80
})

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(x), orient='index').reset_index().rename(
    index=str, columns={0: 'value', 'index': 'claimNumber'})
data['angle'] = data['value']/sum(x.values()) * 2*pi
data['color'] = chart_colors[:len(x)]

p = figure(plot_height=350, title="Pie Chart", toolbar_location=None)

p.wedge(x=0, y=1, radius=0.28,
        start_angle=cumsum('angle', include_zero=True), end_angle=cumsum('angle'),
        color='color', legend='claimNumber', source=data)

p.axis.axis_label=None
p.axis.visible=False
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It helped. I'm new to Python. I tried to use 'data['color'] = chart_colors' instead of 'data['color'] = chart_colors[:len(x)]' and got an error. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's worth stating explicitly: all of the columns of a ColumnDataSource must *always be the same length at all times* (the same as Pandas)